# Cannot save files to cloudinary before handling image upload

Tags: node.js, express, mern, cloudinary

I am new to node.js. Following an online tutorial, I have been working on a mern project for weeks. In the server, I can post new data, but when trying to save a file to cloudinary using cloudinary API, the testing on Insomnia failed again and again. The status code is 500, the error shows that the image could not be uploaded. I checked the codes but there was nothing wrong. Could you help see what issues I have to fix?

Here is the post controller:

```
import PostMessage from "../models/postMessage.js";
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import { fileSizeFormatter } from "../utils/fileUpload.js";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';

export const createPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const {title, tags, content, visibility} = req.body;
    if (!title || !tags || !content || !visibility) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("Please fill in all required fields");
    }
    let fileData = {};
    if (req.file) {
        let uploadedFile;
        try {
            uploadedFile = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
                req.file.path, 
                {folder: "Tect", resource_type: "image"},
            ); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500);
            throw new Error("Image could not be uploaded");
        }

        fileData = {
            fileName: req.file.originalname,
            filePath: uploadedFile.secure_url,
            fileType: req.file.mimetype,
            fileSize: fileSizeFormatter(req.file.size, 2),
        }
    }
    const post = await PostMessage.create({
        user: req.user.id,
        title,
        tags,
        content,
        visibility,
        image: fileData,
    });
    res.status(201).json(post);
});
```

the route:

```
import express from "express";
import { 
    createPost, getPosts, getPost, deletePost, updatePost, getPublicPosts, getPublicStatus, getPublicPost 
} from '../controllers/posts.js';
import { protect } from "../middleware/auth.js";
import { upload } from "../utils/fileUpload.js";
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", protect, upload.single("image"), createPost);
```

the util fildUploader:

```
import multer from "multer";

/**define file storage */
//the first function enables developers to have control on storing files to disk
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "upload");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" +  file.originalname);
    }
});

//specify the format that can be saved
function fileFilter (req, file, cb) {
    // The function should call `cb` with a boolean
    // to indicate if the file should be accepted
    if (
        file.mimetype === "image/png" || 
        file.mimetype === "image/jpg" || 
        file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
    ) {
        // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
        cb(null, false);
    }

}

//file size format
export const fileSizeFormatter = (bytes, decimal) => {
    if (bytes === 0) {
        return "0 Bytes";
    }
    const dm = decimal || 2;
    const sizes = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "YB", "ZB"];
    const index = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1000));
    return(
        parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(1000, index)).toFixed(dm)) + " " + sizes[index]
    );
};

export const upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });
```

I set CLOUDINARY_URL environment variable

but the testing inInsomnia shows that

```
Error: Image could not be uploaded
    at file:///Users/oushinu/Desktop/tect_trial/server/controllers/posts.js:32:19
    at asyncUtilWrap (/Users/oushinu/Desktop/tect_trial/server/node_modules/express-async-handler/index.js:3:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/oushinu/Desktop/tect_trial/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/oushinu/Desktop/tect_trial/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/oushinu/Desktop/tect_trial/server/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:468:21)
```

If remove codes about cloudinary in the controller, post works well.

Comment: The `cloudinary.uploader.upload(...)` can accept a local file path (supported in SDKs only), the actual data (byte array buffer), Data URI (Base64 encoded), or from a remote resource source through HTTP/FTP or S3 bucket. Also, kindly ensure that the directory for the `req.file.path` is accessible (read) from your server application.

Comment: I also used multer package for uploading files. So I created a new folder "upload". The req.file.path is apparently the path to the local folder "upload. This directory is accessible from the server application. I tested: posting a local file works well

Comment: Using console.error, the error is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secure_url')".